# How do I add (and enable) Remote Desktop in my Windows salt state?

Tags: salt-stack

My `windows.sls` works great when I run `salt '*' state.highstate`. How do I also make sure that machines get Remote Desktop enabled via this sls file?

```
# windows.sls

windows:
  pkg.installed:
    - pkgs:
      - rdcman
```

Here's the [salt.module.rdp documentation](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.rdp.html). I just can't figure out how I can define it in my `windows.sls` state.

Answer (score 0):

You can call any module from a state file using the [`module.run`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.module.html) state.

The following should do the job (sorry I didn't test this, I don't have a windows server running salt here):

```
enable_rdp:
  module.run:
    - name: rdp.enable
```